# How to modify text string from this JavaScript file

Tags: magento2, javascript, localisation

I would like to change a text string in this file, to be **Add** or **Added to Basket** depending on which page the user is on:

`app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

To explain, this piece of text is added to the add-to-cart button when the user selects it, at first it is changed from **Add to Cart** to **Adding..**., then to **Added** and finally back to **Add to Cart**
[image]

On the Category View page I would like it to change to **Add** at the end and on the Product View I'd like to change it to **Add to Basket** at the end.

I've used tranlation CSV file in my theme to change **Add to Cart** to **Add to Basket** already.  But this does not translate strings from JavaScript, it's a bug [Magento2 bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20js-translation).
*app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/i18n/en_GB.csv*

Anyway, I don't think translations will work for me here as I would need to use a different translation depending on which page the user is on, and they're both using the Magento_Category module.

I have a solution but I'm not sure if it's best practice, I made a copy of:
 `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

and placed the copy in my theme at: `app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js`

then a changed a section of code to:

```
// Check to see if we're using the form which is present on the category-view page.
if (jQuery(self.element.context).attr('data-role') == "tocart-form") {
    var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add');
} else {
    var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Trolley');
}
```

Is this ok?  Or is there a better way of doing it, I would prefer not to have to override all the JavaScript from this file in my theme.

Comment: please show your csv file path

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, I've updated my Question but I sure this is not it.  The transaltions are working on strings coming from phtml templates etc, and this is a [known bug](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20js-translation)

Answer (score 0):

This is **Magento-2** bug so You can change it by override this file without any issue.

```
app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/Holy/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js
```

You can put your changes to this file.

Comment: yes, this is what I explained in my question, I was wondering if there was a better way in which I would _not to have to override all the JavaScript from this file in my theme_

Comment: Currently you have to go with it.

Answer (score 0):

best way to override `.js` files.

**Helloworld/Learning/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart':'Helloworld_Learning/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
        }
    }
};
```

**Helloworld/Learning/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js**

and change your code as you like

```
// Check to see if we're using the form which is present on the category-view page.
if (jQuery(self.element.context).attr('data-role') == "tocart-form") {
    var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add');
} else {
    var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Trolley');
}
```